# как со свойством filter css всплывашку в этом элементе оставить background белый цвет?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.first {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid;
  background: white;
}

.first span {
  display: none;
  background: white;
}

.first:hover {
  filter: brightness(55%);
}

.first:hover span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border: solid;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"><span>alert</span></div>
<div class="first"><span>alert</span></div>
```

Comment: Никак... оно зависит от родителя, и filter % накладывается уже поверх родительского фильтра. А поставить яркость 180%, чтобы обратно встало на место - не прокатит) Можно вынести span за рамки родителя и показывать при `.first:hover + span`, например.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант.

```css
.first {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid;
  position: relative;
}

.first > div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.first span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.first span {
  display: none;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.first:hover > div {
  filter: brightness(55%);
}

.first:hover span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border: solid;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <span>alert</span>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="first">
  <span>alert</span>
  <div></div>
</div>
```